# Can Django work well with pandas and numpy?

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

I am trying to build a web application that requires intensive mathematical calculations. Can I use Django to populate python charts and pandas dataframe?

Comment: Don't see why not - Django can serve the website and call other Python code to do the calculations. :)

Comment: Yes pretty much Django is not alien to any other Python package.

Comment: Django itself is written in python and support native python code duh. Django will just manage your web app part that's all

Answer (score 6):

You can use any framework to do so. If you worked with Python before I can recommend using Django since you have the same (clear Python) syntax along your project. This is good because you keep the same logic everywhere but should not be your major concern when it comes to choosing the right framework for your needs. So for example if you are a top Ruby-On-Rails developer I would not suggest to learn Django just because of Pandas.

In general: A lot of packages/libraries are written in other languages but you will still be able to use them in Django/Python. So for example the famous "Elasticsearch" Searchbackend has its roots in JAVA but is still used in a lot of Django apps.

But it also goes the other way around "Celery" is written in Python but can be used in Node.js or PHP. There are hundreds of examples but I think you get the Point.

I hope that I brought some light into the darkness. If you have questions please leave them in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a lot of the experience in JAVA and some experience in Python. I am considering Python cuz the app needs a to do a lot of math work. And Django appears to be the most popular now. My concern is that can I populate charts like from matplotlib?

Comment: Django is a good solid framework which proved to be stable and yes its popular since Python is gaining more attention in the recent years and so did Django. Again I really recommend to use Django but please remember that you asked a Question with a Django tag and of course we Django developers will tell you that its the best (thats why we use it) but somebody else would tell you a different story. To your concern with Matlib here is a full documentation for using marlin charts in Django http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Django.html